# Why is the PHP preg_match returning empty?

Tags: php, regex, vimeo

```
// gets video ID from URL
$url = "http://vimeo.com/12345678";
preg_match("/vimeo.*\/(\d+)/i", $url, $vimeoID);
var_dump($vimeoID);
```

Variable dump:

```
array(0) {
}
```

It works [here](http://www.switchplane.com/awesome/preg-match-regular-expression-tester?pattern=/vimeo.%2a%5C/%28%5Cd%2b%29/i&subject=vimeo.com/124565) so what am I missing?

Comment: Try using single quotes for your string instead of double, or doubling each of your backslashes.  What version of PHP are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be more specific with your regex to prevent a greedy expression:

```
preg_match(":vimeo.\w{2,4}/(\d+):i", $url, $vimeoID);
```

Comment: Greediness wouldn't prevent a match; it would (could) just match more than desired.

Answer (score 0):

For me works as expected. i get this..

```
array(2) {
 [0]=>
 string(18) "vimeo.com/12345678"
 [1]=>
 string(8) "12345678"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`preg_match("/vimeo\.com\/([0-9]{1,})/i", $url, $vimeoID);`